# What determines flexibility?

Tags: muscle, physiology, physical-health, stretching

I'm sorry if this doesn't qualify as a question for this stack. I thought about putting it on "Physical Fitness" but don't think it fits there and is better of here. Please move it not appropriate. Thank you!

I recently read an article (will post source if I find it) that featured a story of a person who was able to attend a hip-replacement surgery of an elderly person. The author mentions that this elderly was able to stretch their leg close to 90°. I suppose this was meant to refer to supine hamstring stretching.
But as soon as the elderly was under narcosis, the surgeon (I guess) was able to stretch the leg far beyond this point. Whilst noting how it is astonishing what the body can do, once the mind gets out of the way. Due to the puzzled look of the author.
The author thus concludes that the main contributing factor for flexibility is actually not short muscles or similar but the mind putting a safety mechanism in place to not get injured due to overstretching.

Coming from this article I wonder what actually determines flexibility. Is this conclusion sound? Or does the author has a misconception following purely visible clues.
I myself have tried to improve my flexibility with little to no improvements for about 10 years now.
This video https://youtu.be/Qf8dmyg2jck summarizes and compares 32 studies (links on the video). It concludes that there seems to be no evidence that forced (over)stretching has any advantage over "relaxed" stretching.
Which would counter the conclusion the author of above mentioned article made, in my opinion.

So what determines flexibility?

Comment: I think your question would actually be more appropriate on Fitness, but before I migrate it you need to find that article that prompted your question. It's central to your question and others might not interpret it as you have, so both sites will want to read the original.

Comment: Oh really? It's just an example though, (I don't want to discuss the article) but I'll will search it. Could you give me a hint why it's better over there? I found those answers are more for personal fitness/individual advice rather than scientific background. It was difficult to decide between the two stacks for this question.

Comment: The article is needed because we can't respond to "I read something somewhere" questions. Doing so requires us to rely entirely on your interpretation and summary of the article when we might interpret it differently if we were able to read it. I think it's a better fit in Fitness because this kind of question is their bread and butter while it's rather a niche question here that I predict will gather few, if any, answers. If you really want it left here we can do that, but I think you'll get better answers on Fitness.

Comment: You should check-out this paper on [use of muscle relaxants during hip surgery](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT03219294), it might clear a few things up before you edit your question into shape.